# Can't login to a specific ASP.NET website using python requests

Tags: python, asp.net, python-requests, login-script

So I've been trying for the last 6 hours to make this work, but I couldn't and endless searches didn't help, So I guess I'm either doing something very fundamental wrong, or it's just a trivial bug which happens to match my logic so I need extra eyes to help me fix it.
The website url is [this](https://www.wes.org/appstatus/).
I wrote a piece of messy python code to just login and read the next page, but All I get is a nasty 500 error saying something on the server went wrong processing my request.
Here is the request made by a browser which works just fine, no problem.
HTTP Response code to this request is 302 (Redirect)

```
POST /appstatus/index.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.wes.org
Connection: close
Content-Length: 303
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://www.wes.org
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://www.wes.org/appstatus/index.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=bu2gemmlh3hvp4f5lqqngrbp; _ga=GA1.2.1842963052.1473348318; _gat=1

__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTg3MTMwMDc1NA9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8PFgIeBFRleHRkZGRk9rP20Uj9SdsjOKNUBlbw55Q01zI%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=189D346C&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBQK6lf6LBAKf%2B9bUAgK9%2B7qcDgK8w4S2BALowqJjoU1f0Cg%2FEAGU6r2IjpIPG8BO%2BiE%3D&txtUID=Email%40Removed.com&txtPWD=PASSWORDREMOVED&Submit=Log+In&Hidden1=
```

and this one is the request made by my script.

```
POST /appstatus/index.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.wes.org
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://www.wes.org
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Referer: https://www.wes.org/appstatus/indexca.aspx
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=nxotmb55jjwf5x4511rwiy45
Content-Length: 303

txtPWD=PASSWORDREMOVED&Submit=Log+In&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBQK6lf6LBAKf%2B9bUAgK9%2B7qcDgK8w4S2BALowqJjoU1f0Cg%2FEAGU6r2IjpIPG8BO%2BiE%3D&txtUID=Email%40Removed.com&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTg3MTMwMDc1NA9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8PFgIeBFRleHRkZGRk9rP20Uj9SdsjOKNUBlbw55Q01zI%3D&Hidden1=&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=189D346C
```

And this is the script making the request, I'm sorry if it's so messy, just need something quick.

```
import requests
import bs4
import urllib.parse
def main():
    session = requests.Session()
    headers = {"Origin": "https://www.wes.org",
               "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
               "Cache-Control": "max-age=0", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", "Connection": "close",
               "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
               "Referer": "https://www.wes.org/appstatus/indexca.aspx", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
               "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    r = session.get('https://www.wes.org/appstatus/index.aspx',headers=headers)
    cookies = r.cookies
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
    viewState=urllib.parse.quote(str(soup.select('#__VIEWSTATE')[0]).split('value="')[1].split('"/>')[0])
    viewStateGenerator=urllib.parse.quote(str(soup.select('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')[0]).split('value="')[1].split('"/>')[0])
    eventValidation=urllib.parse.quote(str(soup.select('#__EVENTVALIDATION')[0]).split('value="')[1].split('"/>')[0])
    paramsPost = {}
    paramsPost.update({'__VIEWSTATE':viewState})
    paramsPost.update({'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewStateGenerator})
    paramsPost.update({'__EVENTVALIDATION':eventValidation})
    paramsPost.update({"txtUID": "My@Email.Removed"})
    paramsPost.update({"txtPWD": "My_So_Called_Password"})
    paramsPost.update({"Submit": "Log In"})
    paramsPost.update({"Hidden1": ""})
    response = session.post("https://www.wes.org/appstatus/index.aspx", data=paramsPost, headers=headers,
                            cookies=cookies)
    print("Status code:", response.status_code) #Outputs 500.
    #print("Response body:", response.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing way too much work and in doing so not passing valid data,you extract value attribute directly i.e `.select_one('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')["value"]` and the same for all the rest, the cookies will be set in the Session object after your initial get so the logic boils down to:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"}
        r = session.get('https://www.wes.org/appstatus/index.aspx', headers=headers)

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
        viewState = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')["value"]
        viewStateGenerator = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')["value"]
        eventValidation = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')["value"]
        paramsPost = {'__VIEWSTATE': viewState,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewStateGenerator,
                      '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventValidation,"txtUID": "My@Email.Removed",
                    "txtPWD": "My_So_Called_Password",
                      "Submit": "Log In","Hidden1": ""}
        response = session.post("https://www.wes.org/appstatus/index.aspx", data=paramsPost, headers=headers)
        print("Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Python by convention uses CamelCase for class names and lowercase with underscores to separate multiple words, you might want to consider applying that to your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess you're right, Your code is much more cleaner so it's easier to debug and understand. I'll try to learn how to write cleaner code from now on. Thanks again for your help.